# ShhFilter: ValueError: {'code': -32000, 'message': 'filter not found'}

Tags: web3.py, shh

For `web3.py==v5.0.1`:

`web3.geth.shh.newMessageFilter` used to return the `filter` on `v4.x.x` but now it only returns the `filter_id`, so I received the filter object using `w3.eth.filter(filter_id='0x')`.

The approach on the following code was working on `web3==v4.x.x`, but now I receive following error: `shh: ValueError: {'code': -32000, 'message': 'filter not found'}`for [Listening For Events](https://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/filters.html?highlight=log_loop#examples-listening-for-events).

---

Example code:

```py
from web3.auto import w3
import time

from web3 import Web3, HTTPProvider
web3 = Web3(HTTPProvider('http://localhost:8545'))

def handle_event(event):
    print(event)

def log_loop(event_filter, poll_interval):
    while True:
        for event in event_filter.get_new_entries():
            handle_event(event)
        time.sleep(poll_interval)

def main():
    filter_id = web3.geth.shh.newMessageFilter({'topic': '0x12340000', 'privateKeyID': recipient_private})
    myFilter = web3.eth.filter(filter_id=filter_id)
    log_loop(myFilter, 2)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The error I am getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "example.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "example.py", line 19, in main
    log_loop(myFilter, 2)
  File "example.py", line 12, in log_loop
    for event in event_filter.get_new_entries():
  File "/home/netlab/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/web3/_utils/filters.py", line 124, in get_new_entries
    log_entries = self._filter_valid_entries(self.web3.eth.getFilterChanges(self.filter_id))
  File "/home/netlab/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/web3/eth.py", line 402, in getFilterChanges
    "eth_getFilterChanges", [filter_id],
  File "/home/netlab/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/web3/manager.py", line 97, in request_blocking
    raise ValueError(response["error"])
ValueError: {'code': -32000, 'message': 'filter not found'}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Shh.newMessageFilter(self, criteria)](https://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/web3.geth.html#web3.geth.txpool.Shh.newMessageFilter)

> Create a new filter id. This filter id can be used with `ShhFilter` to
>   poll for new messages that match the set of criteria.

I was able to fix the problem by changing:

`for event in event_filter.get_new_entries():` => as  `for event in w3.geth.shh.getMessages(filter_id):`

---

```py
from web3.auto import w3
import time

from web3 import Web3, HTTPProvider
web3 = Web3(HTTPProvider('http://localhost:8545'))

def handle_event(event):
    print(event)

def log_loop(filter_id, poll_interval):
    while True:
        for event in w3.geth.shh.getMessages(filter_id):
            handle_event(event)
        time.sleep(poll_interval)

def main():
    filter_id = web3.geth.shh.newMessageFilter({'topic': '0x12340000', 'privateKeyID': recipient_private})  
    log_loop(filter_id, 2)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```